# how to get the value of a range input and pass it to a PHP variable ?

Tags: php, html

How to get the value of a range input and pass it to a PHP variable ?

```
<input type=range min=0 max=100 value=50 name="price">
```

Comment: Same way you'd get the value of any other input... `$_POST['price']` or `$_GET['price']`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way you get the value of any other input.

Put it in a form, submit the form, then use `$_GET['fieldname']` (or `$_POST`).

Comment: Can i get that value somehow before submitting the form ? i mean i want to use it in the same page not another one

Comment: @exchanger3145 — Not with PHP. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Answer (score 2):

index.php

```
<form action="check.php" method="POST">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" name="price">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

check.php

```
<?php

echo $_POST['price'];

?>
```